# RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 17584072992

Tags: three.js

When I use three.js to load the stl model, the problem in the title always occurs. I have searched for a long time and have not found the corresponding solution. Here are some pictures of my problem：

```
const loader = new STLLoader();

// Binary files

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 });

loader.load('/pr2_head_pan.stl', function (geometry) {

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh.position.set(0, - 0.37, - 0.6);
    mesh.rotation.set(- Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2);

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(mesh);

});
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu4Qs.png][Project folder picture]

```
RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 17584072992
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVV6C.png][picture of error message]
Thank you for your help！

Comment: You tried to create an ArrayBuffer that is bigger than 2GB-1 (2^32-1) on a 32-bit system or 8GB (2^33) on a 64-bit system. 17584072992 bytes is around 16.38 GiB, too much memory

Comment: What should I do? Because I'm still a beginner.

Comment: How did you get the model?

Anyway, according to https://sbcode.net/threejs/meshphongmaterial/
"Blinn–Phong reflection model is more computationally-expensive to use than the MeshLambertMaterial, MeshNormalMaterial and MeshBasicMaterial so if performance needs to be considered, then one option you have is to only use it when necessary."

Comment: The model is obtained from the example of three.js I posted on github